# Find occurrence of a string which has another string preceding it

Tags: regex

I want to find the last occurrence of a 10 digit character which has createdtimestamps= in it.

I have written a regex to find the last occurrence of 10 digit characters but not able to add the createdtimestamps= condition to it

My regex is `(\d{10}(?!.*\d{10}))`

But it also matches where created timestamps= is not there

Sample text:

> folders from an
>   application.  source=API  threat_score=78 created_timestamps=1540273980,
>   1540352100, 1540795080, 1541825820,
>   1544766960    _id=jhjshwymAFgwAMTyAEtF    user_name=x.x.x.    message=From Last
>   Incident: Large number of deletes. 96 in 1.0 minute(s). Incident
>   estimated to have a 1% chance of being
>   normal.   inserted_timestamp=2018-12-14T06:54:26  activity_type=Delete

Expected output : 1544766960

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/CoZ0Yu/1

Tried putting a And condition but the last negative lookbehind stops working

Comment: This works: `(?<=created_timestamps=)[\d- ,]*(\d{10})(?!\d{10})`        Try putting this in the above site.

Comment: This works. Thanks :D

Comment: Could you please mark the right answer with green tick below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works: 
`(?<=created_timestamps=)[\d- ,]*(\d{10})(?!\d{10})`

Try putting this in the regex101 website.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://regex101.com/r/1UZVe5/1) should be what you want:

> (?<=created_timestamps=)[\d, ]*(\d{10})

Group 1 is the desired string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use such pattern: `created_timestamps=(\d{10})(?:, (\d{10}))*`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Alvn5Y/1)

Explanation:

`created_timestamps=` - match `created_timestamps=` literally

`(\d{10})` - match ten digits and store it in first capturing group

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`, (\d{10})` - match comma, space and then ten digit and store it in capturing group

`(\d{10})(?:, (\d{10}))*` - match `(\d{10})(?:, (\d{10}))` zero or more times.

The last part is where the magic begins: if you have more than one 10-digit number, then your number will be stored in second capturing group, as it's qunatified, so in second capturing group there will be stored last match, which will be number you are looking for.

On the other hand, when there is only one number, it will stored in first capturing group and it can be obtained from there (there will be no second capturing group).

So, match your pattern, check if second capturing group exists, if so, it's number you are looking for, if not, then it is in first capturing group.

Alternatively, you could use `created_timestamps=(?:\d{10}[, ]++)+(\d{10})`

[Second demo](https://regex101.com/r/Alvn5Y/2)

Comment: This also works, but the only problem here is that my solution limits to define capture group in the start only. You cant dynamically choose it

Answer (score 0):

Try this function. Used the regExp grouping feature to capture the needed data

```
    function Replace_(str) {
       var patt = /.*created_timestamps.*(\d{10}).*/i;
       var res = str.replace(patt, '$1');
       return res;
    }
```

[Demo](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G2PEUYAJ9WQS)